# Is there a way to indicate to the xaml designer to ignore a specific tag only during design-time?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

sometimes the VS/blend designer can't render the xaml because of some parsing error. but it compiles and run just fine. and i could just comment the problem tag/line and the xaml renders fine again. I know of the ignorable attribute but it ignores an attribute during compilation. I would like to have it the other way, to make the xaml designer ignore a tag during design-time but allowed to compiles it for run time. so, is there a way to indicate to the xaml designer to do this? i am using Visual Studio 2012 and Blend 2012

Comment: Could you provide an example of the XAML you're working with that causes the problem?

Comment: I have custom generic TargetedTriggerAction and EventTrigger with generic property that is causing the Designer to complain...

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to just mark a `Setter` for the `d:IsHidden` property (which yes does use the ignorable attribute) in the parent object.Resources. So something for example like (SL/WP/WinRT style example, may need edited for using x:Type and/or Style.Triggers if for WPF but the concept is the same.)

Added to namespaces if not already there by default;

```
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

and an example;

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="RadioButton"><!-- Could Substitute TargetType for a specific control
         <Setter Property="d:IsHidden" Value="True"/>
     </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>

    <RadioButton/><!-- This guy should now be hidden in Design Time -->

</Grid>
```

Hope this helps.